# What kinds of commands can't be executed in a transaction block?

Tags: postgresql

I found that CREATE DATABASE and VACUUM and a few other commands can't be executed in a transaction block (one defined by BEGIN...COMMIT)

Could you explain  the reason? Is this because of intentional design or implementation limitation?

As a rule of thumb, what kinds of commands can't be executed in a transaction block?
It seems CREATE TABLE can be executed in a transaction block. So not all DDL commands can't.

Thanks.

Comment: [Transactional DDL in PostgreSQL: A Competitive Analysis](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis)

Comment: There is no ready-made list, but each [SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) says in the documentation if it can run in a transaction block or not.